# R: Gwidget simpleError in envRefInferField , for gedit

Tags: r, gwidgets

For every gedit i have i get this error on the console line whenever i run my entire R of widget code

```
   <simpleError in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv): ‘no_items’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Entry”>
```

Here is some example of my gedits

```
textBox_keyword1 <- gedit(text="",container=grp_keywordSearch)
textBox_keyword2 <- gedit(text="",container=grp_keywordSearch)
textBox_keyword3 <- gedit(text="",container=grp_keywordSearch)
textBox_keyword4 <- gedit(text="",container=grp_keywordSearch)

textBox_numTweet <- gedit(text="",container=grp_numTweet)
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: This looks like a comment made recently where the script is running under RStudio. Is that the case?

Comment: yes i ran this on Rstudio, im also using Gwidgets and 
gwidgetstcltk

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any solution to this. The use of tk with RStudio can lead to issues, atleast that was the case awhile ago and I don't know that it has changed. The package on github `gWidgetsWWW2` might be of help here. It mostly works the same but uses the browser for display. You need to install that with devtools though, as it isn't on CRAN (yet).